# What is the SRS code for Lambert Conformal Conic projection and GCS Everest Definition 1962?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, proj

I have a shapefile with Geographic Coordinate System is "GCS_Everest Definition 1962" and the Projected Coordinate System is "Lambert_Conformal_Conic". I want to add this shapefile in Geoserver. But I don't know which code is used as the SRS for this Projection System. I don't know what to put in "Declared SRS" field.
Here is the WKT

```
PROJCS["Lambert Conformal Conic",   
GEOGCS["GCS_Everest Definition 1962",     
DATUM["Everest Definition 1962",       
SPHEROID["Everest Definition 1962", 
6377301.243, 300.8017255654936]],    
 PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0],     
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],     
AXIS["Longitude", EAST],     
AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]],   
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],   
PARAMETER["central_meridian", 68.0],   
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 32.5],   
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1", 35.31445944444445],   
PARAMETER["false_easting", 2743196.4],   
PARAMETER["false_northing", 914398.8],   
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0],   
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2", 29.655283888888892],   
UNIT["m", 1.0],   
AXIS["x", EAST],   
AXIS["y", NORTH]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always paste (or upload) your .prj file in to http://prj2epsg.org/search and see if it can work it out for you.

Comment: It gives following error either i add the .prj file or put the wkt in the editbox "Recursive call while creating a 'DefaultFactory' object."
Do you know anything about it?

Comment: can you add the WKT to the question?

Comment: Please check it out.

Comment: did you check it?

Comment: it works for me

Comment: Thanx, it works now. Thanx alot. Probably there were a problem on the site couple of days ago.

Comment: looks like a useful website, but for me pasting that WKT in I'm now seeing `Invalid WKT syntax: Database failure while creating a 'Identifier' object for code "6377301.243"` (and same error for my own WKT I was trying with)

Answer (score 3):

This might be the correct EPSG Code (4044):  http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4044/

Confirm the parmeters based on the WKT definition :  http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4044/prettywkt/

Comment: Thats only the datum. You have to add the parameters for lcc projection to get it working.