# Is EPSG:3857 correct projection for PDF in Lambert Conformal Conic projection?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, pdf

Given the following NEATLINE from the results of gdalinfo on my Geospatial PDF:

```
  NEATLINE=POLYGON ((-1340591.5297333347 -260482.28440259479,-1340591.0579001249 1878014.4171204455,3081498.0723039531 1878014.3548907496,3081497.6538160094 -260482.78408519758,-1340591.5297333347 -260482.28440259479))
```

I used the following code to convert the result to EPSG:4326 coordinates

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr

x = [-1340591.5297333347,-1340591.0579001249,3081498.0723039531,3081497.6538160094,-1340591.5297333347]
y = [-260482.28440259479,1878014.4171204455,1878014.3548907496,-260482.78408519758,-260482.28440259479]

i = 0

while i < 5:

    pointX = x[i]
    pointY = y[i]

    # Spatial Reference System
    inputEPSG = 3857
    outputEPSG = 4326

    # create a geometry from coordinates
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(pointX, pointY)

    # create coordinate transformation
    inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(inputEPSG)

    outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(outputEPSG)

    coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

    # transform point
    point.Transform(coordTransform)

    # print point in EPSG 4326
    print point.GetY(), point.GetX()

    i += 1
```

This results in:

```
-2.33930197857 -12.0427386092
16.6318711337 -12.0427343707
16.6318705981 27.6815681634
-2.33930646355 27.681564404
-2.33930197857 -12.0427386092
```

It looks close to being right, but the 27 degrees longitude on lines 3 and 4 should be more around 54 degrees East.

The additional information from the gdalinfo is as follows:

```
PROJCS["Lambert_Conformal_Conic",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137.0,298.257223563],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",25.0],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",7.66666666],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",38.3333333],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
GeoTransform =
  -2133343.372843582, 754.0130468353923, 3.981217275795919
  2035401.595692971, 3.953040951345574, -753.9627451388365
```

I assume I'm using the correct inputEPSG in my code, if not, does anyone know what I should use in its place?

I guess it is also entirely possible that the NEATLINE is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you think that your neatline is in EPSG:3857, and not Lambert Conformal Conical?

Comment: Because according to this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41355/what-is-the-srs-code-for-lambert-conformal-conic-projection-and-gcs-everest-defi) and the link in the first answer, when I paste the information above (PROJCS["Lambert_Conf...) in, the first result is 3857.  Therefore I assumed the NEATLINE would be that projection as well.  If this is wrong, how can I determine the projection of the NEATLINE?  I am not the creator of this PDF, but I do use them.

Comment: I assume that the neatline has the same projection as the PDF. The proj.4 string would be `+proj=lcc +lat_1=7.66666666 +lat_2=38.3333333 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`. There does not have to be an EPSG code for it.

Comment: I entered that information into [cs2cs](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/) and determined it was Africa_Lambert_Conformal_Conic (SRID 102024).  I see now how you determined that proj.4 string.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: SRID 102024 is defined as `+proj=lcc +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs` which has slightly different parallels than your PDF. If possible, use the proj.4 string in your code.

Answer (score 1):

To proof the projection string, you can load the WKT of the neatline directly into QGIS, on a tiles background:

[image]

The green line uses the CRS from your PDF, and the red one uses SRID 102024. Project CRS is the first one, that's why it looks like a rectangle.

By the way, I had put your PDF WKT definition into a .prj file, and ran gdalsrsinfo on it to get the proj.4 string.